# Preserve upvotes as stars when moving comments to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

Moving comments to chat is a somewhat destructive operation since the upvotes on the comments are lost.

In some cases – especially when there are a lot of comments – this is rather annoying, because it becomes much harder to distinguish the insightful "gems" from the "noise".

Could upvotes be preserved as chat stars when moving the comments?

Comment: @Catija Thanks, guess I didn't find that because I searched only for "vote" and not "upvote". Do'h.

Comment: The typo in the title probably didn't help, either... with the similar questions feature on the ask page.